# Running java program on web server

Tags: java, php

I need to run a single java program (which will change the content of some text files) on my new website. What's the easiest way to do that for example using php code?
Do I need to install JVM or any other software in order for this to work?
Please guide on how to do this step by step if possible.

Comment: What you want is a web application : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385105/how-do-i-get-started-building-web-apps-with-java

Answer (score 0):

You have to install a Java Runtime Environment (JRE) on your server to be able to run a java program.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7-downloads-1880261.html

To execute a java program in php, you can simply use the `exec()` function :

```
exec("java -jar yourProgram.jar");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: So if I have access to the server only by FTP client (the page is hosted on someones server) should i download JRE version for 32-bit linux and then copy it to the server using FTP?

Comment: Yes it should be possible if you send the uncompressed folder through FTP. But maybe the `java` command will not be recognized on the server so you will have to put the whole path to java in your php command (something like `exec("/install_dir/jre1.8.0_71/bin/java -jar yourProgram.jar");`